# Add column with count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

When I do "select count(*) from users", it returns the data in the following format:

```
mysql> select count(*) from users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        100 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I would like to get the data in the following format instead.

```
+---------+----------+
| key     | count    |
+---------+----------+
| my_count|   100    |
+---------+----------+
```

The reason is to feed this data to a pre-built widget which expects the data in the above format.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

I tried various options such as "group by" but couldn't get it working.

```
mysql> select count(*) from users;
```

```
+---------+----------+
| key     | count    |
+---------+----------+
| my_count|   100    |
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a string literal to your select clause:

```
SELECT 'my_count' AS `key`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users;
```

Note that `key` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, so we must escape it using backticks.

If you intended to use `GROUP BY`, then you probably want a query like this:

```
SELECT `key`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users
GROUP BY `key`;
```